# htaccess - Redirecting php files

Tags: .htaccess

I am writing my .htaccess file for my website. It contains 30+ php files that have act as front-end for the courses.

I have tried the code below but whenever you access my website: www.conuplugs.com, it redirects to COMP248 for some reason

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/comp232.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/comp248.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/engr201.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/engr213.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/comp249.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen228.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen287.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/engr233.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/comp348.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/comp352.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/encs282.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/engr202.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/comp346.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen331.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen341.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/engr371.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/elec275.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/comp335.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen342.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen343.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen344.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen345.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen384.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/engr391.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen357.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen390.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/engr301.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen321.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen490.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/engr392.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/soen385.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ class/comp354.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

As mentioned earlier, this redirects to COMP248.php, how can I fix this?

Comment: Well, this rule set smells of a redirection loop, since any of the targets will again be matched by the generic pattern `^(.*)$`. The two `RewriteCond`s you give will only influence the single `RewriteRule` immediately following those conditions. So anything targeting an existing php file will _again_ be rewritten by the first unconditional rewriting rule which happens to be the one rewriting to `class/comp248.php`. The http server realizes that the target pattern did not change, actually, so the rewriting process is stopped.

Comment: I suggest you explain in detail what it actually is you want to achieve instead of telling us how you think you can achieve it. So what are those paths you actually try to rewrite? And how should the rewriting engine decide to _which_ php script it is meant to rewrite to?